# Weekday wise plotting in python

Tags: python, pandas, plot

I have yearly data for labor hour. I want to plot the yearly data for each week day i.e. monday , tuesday , wednesday etc. I have tried to filter the data for a certain period and then aggregated the Labor hour for each day of the filtered data.

The code is as below:

```
df2 = df1[(df1['STime'] > '1900-01-01 07:51:00') & (df1['ETime'] < '1900-01-01 18:00:00')]

df3 = df2.groupby('Edate', as_index=False).agg({"LaborReq.Actual Hrs": "sum"})

df3.plot(x='Edate', y='LaborReq.Actual Hrs')
```

The plot I have right now:

[image]

How do I get them for each weekday i.e. all monday's for the entire period?

Sorry, if my doubt is basic. I am new to python and data analysis.

Comment: You can create a new column in `df1` that holds the day of the week for that row. Then you can groupby day of the week and plot. To generate the day-of-week column, look at the [`dt.dayofweek` attribute](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.dayofweek.html).

Comment: yeah it worked . Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
df1['day_of_week'] = df1.STime.apply(to_datetime).dt.dayofweek
# replace day names
df1.day_of_week.replace({0:'Monday',1:'Tuesday',2:'Wednesday',3:'Thursday',4:'Friday',5:'Saturday',6:'Sunday'}, inplace=True)
# some labor by day group
df2 = df1.groupby('day_of__week').sum()
```